# Register Custom menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

How to register this menu in wordpress dynamically ?

i'am having problem to dynamic menu in wordpress

```html
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Division</a>
<ul class="dropotron dropotron-level-0 center" style="-moz-user-select: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; left: 184.767px; top: 29px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
<li ><a style="display: block;" href="real-estate.html">Real Estate</a></li>
<li><a style="display: block;" href="waterpump.html">Water Pump</a></li>
<li ><a style="display: block;" href="fmcg.html">FMCG</a></li>
<li ><a style="display: block;" href="infrastructure.html">Infrastructure Project</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
<li class="break"><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
<li ><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: this will be helpful http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: tnx bro.. but i wanted to dynamic this menu to wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i'm fully understand what you'r meant when you say 'register this menu in wordpress dynamically', but if you meant to register custom menu and display it so follow this:

put this code on the 'functions.php' file: (if you are not using a theme of your own then create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you didn't already)

```
function register_your_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('your-menu-location',__( 'Your Menu Description' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_your_menu' );
```

*register your new menu - it will display the new menu on the admin panel so set it as you like.

put this code on the place you want the menu to appear on the theme and customize the '$defaults' settings as you like (you can find more info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'your-menu-location' ) ) {   
    $defaults = array(
        'theme_location'  => 'your-menu-location',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
    );

     wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
}
```